# Error 500 with NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, ajax, eclipse, jsp, stack-trace

I'm deploying my spring project on a VM (ubuntu 14) and when i use a button that perform an ajax call it gives error500 with in the stack NoSuchElementException pointed to an iterator.

My app work fine on eclipse and also when deploying in my VM, so i exported the VM (where all work fine) to the client computer, but still giving the error 500.

Here is the trace:

```
HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /executeComparison.jsp at line 7

type Exception report

message An exception occurred processing JSP page /executeComparison.jsp at 
line 7

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from 
fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page 
/executeComparison.jsp at line 7

4: 
5: <%
6: System.out.println("I'm comparing");
7: ComputeDifference.printDiffs(ComputeDifference.getAllDiffs("P1", "P2"));
8: String data = "active";
9: out.print(data);
10: out.flush();


 Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.util.NoSuchElementException
java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:834)
comparator.ComputeDifference.compare(ComputeDifference.java:212)
comparator.ComputeDifference.getAllDiffs(ComputeDifference.java:29)
org.apache.jsp.executeComparison_jsp._jspService(executeComparison_jsp.java:70)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache 
Tomcat/7.0.53 logs.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.53
```

I dont think its something with the iterator or with the java code seen its working fine on eclipse and also in my VM in my computer, the bug is there when i'm using the same VM but on client computer, the ajax call fail and give the following error

```
jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4 GET 
https://193.169.100.12:8443/DMX.v.3.10/executeComparison.jsp?
rand=0.9844812755765802 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Here is the ajax call:

```
        function evaluateDelta() {
        var rand = Math.random();
        $.ajax({
            url: "executeComparison.jsp",
            dataType: 'text',
            data: { rand: rand },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("got the difference");
                displayDelta();
            }
        });

    }
```

And here is the jsp page:

```
 <%@page import="java.util.*"%>
 <%@page import="comparator.ComputeDifference"%>

 <%
  System.out.println("I'm comparing");
  ComputeDifference.printDiffs(ComputeDifference.getAllDiffs("P1", "P2"));
  String data = "active";
  out.print(data);
  out.flush();
 %>
```

When i'm checking logs i found "i'm comparing printed" which means ajax went to jsp but jsp failed on the next line as shown on stack trace.

And finally here is the function where the iterator pointed on the stack (the one in the syso " System.out.println("\r\n\r\n------------  Command "+it.next()+"\r\n\r\n"); ":

```
 static public void compare (String fileName1,String fileName2) throws IOException{

    String filePath1="C:/Users/Mike/Desktop/"+fileName1+".txt";
    String filePath2="C:/Users/Mike/Desktop/"+fileName2+".txt"; 

    BufferedReader in = null;   
    BufferedReader inN=null;
    BufferedReader in2=null;
    BufferedReader in2N=null;
    String line = "", line2= "";
    ArrayList<String> commands=ComputeDifference.getCommands(filePath1);
    Iterator<String> it = commands.iterator();
    boolean command=true;
    try {   

        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath1));
        inN = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath1));  inN.readLine();
        in2= new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath2));      
        in2N= new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath2));  in2N.readLine();

        File file = new File("C:/Users/Mike/Desktop/command1.txt");
        File file1 = new File("C:/Users/Mike/Desktop/command2.txt");
        File fileDiff = new File("C:/Users/Mike/Desktop/commandDiff.txt");

        PrintStream printStreamToFile = new PrintStream(file);         
        PrintStream printStreamToFile1 = new PrintStream(file1);
        PrintStream printStreamToFileDiff = new PrintStream(fileDiff);
        int i=0;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null ) {
                String next=inN.readLine();

                System.setOut(printStreamToFile);
                System.out.println(line);

                if(next != null && next.contains("#")){

                 command=true;


                    while (command == true && (line2 = in2.readLine())  != null) {

                        String next2=in2N.readLine();
                        System.setOut(printStreamToFile1);
                        System.out.println(line2);

                        if(next2 != null && next2.contains("#")){
                            System.setOut(printStreamToFileDiff);
                            if(i!=0){


                            System.out.println("\r\n\r\n------------  Command "+it.next()+"\r\n\r\n");

                            List<String> original = fileToLines("command1");
                            List<String> revised  = fileToLines("command2");

                            System.setOut(printStreamToFileDiff);
                            Patch<String> patch = DiffUtils.diff(original, revised);
                            for (Delta<String> delta: patch.getDeltas()) {

                               System.setOut(printStreamToFileDiff);
                                System.out.println(delta);


                            }
                            }
                            else{
                                i++;
                                it.next();
                                } 
                            printStreamToFile1.close();
                            file1.delete();
                            file1.createNewFile();
                            printStreamToFile1=new PrintStream(file1);  
                            command=false;
                        }
                                                }   
                            printStreamToFile.close();
                            file.delete();
                            file.createNewFile();
                            printStreamToFile=new PrintStream(file);  
            }

        }   

System.setOut(ApplicationConstant.console);


} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {

    if (in != null) {
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
    if (in2 != null) {
        try {
            in2.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }
}
}
```

Any idea were this error can came from i searched all forums and websites i know but in vain.

Many thanks.

Comment: Your `compare` code is calling `it.next()` when there is no next element to get.

Comment: yes thats what the trace says, but the code is working fine in eclipse and in my VM on my computer, the error is generated only when i'm using my VM on client computer (same VM, exported from virtualbox and then imported on client computer).

Answer (score 0):

You must check if `Iterator.hasNext()` before calling `Iterator.next()`. There is a possibility of NoSuchElementException in your code even if it is working on some environments.

See also:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html